# How to upload files onto arbitrary directories in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-storage, python-django-storages

I'm developing a file manager with Django. I'm using SFTP file server and [django-storage package](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/sftp.html) for managing files.

Well I developed some Apis for users to create and modify directories under their-own root-directory (which is abstract to the users) so far. Now I want to able users to upload their files onto their sub-directories or move files between those sub-directories but I don't know how?!

This is the model I'm using for file management:

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(format(instance.owner.id, '010d'), filename)

class UploadedFile(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

As you can see, currently files will be uploaded to `<server-root>/user_<10digit-userid>/` directory.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is really quite complex, because it's not just a matter of moving files around. Managing directories (creating directories) and listing them, etc... requires you to actually keep the directory structure in the db as well. You should take a look at the django-filer package, either as example of how to do this or just use it.

Comment: @dirkgroten Yes this is complex. Actually I managed to upload file wherever user wants. Now I'm working on moving files, copy files and renaming of directories! The hard part of those issues is renaming files and save that change in DB. Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last I added an extra `CharField` to my model named `upload_to` and I used it in `user_directory_path` function to indicate sub-directory of the file.

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    if instance.upload_to != '' and instance.upload_to[-1] != '/':
        upload_to = instance.upload_to + '/'
    else:
        upload_to = instance.upload_to
    return 'user_{0}/{1}{2}'.format(format(instance.owner.id, '010d'), upload_to, filename)

class UploadedFile(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
    upload_to = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
```